# How to give all privileges to a new user that I created 'user@%'

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I switch to MySQL 8 recently; earlier I was using MySQL 5.7 in GCP. I know questions like this have already been asked, but I didn't have any luck. My question is, I want to create a new user just say 'user1' and grant all privileges to a user account on all databases.

The query I am using for user creation:

```
CREATE USER 'user-1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'user_password';
```

For privileges:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user-1'@'%';
```

This privileges query used to work on MySQL 5.7, but when I try to run this query in MySQL 8, I get this error (**I logged in as root user and MySQL is in GCP**):

```
SQL Error (1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

I also tried to run this query one after another like this:

```
CREATE USER 'user-1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'user_password';


GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user-1'@'%';
```

But still I get the same error. I came to know that in MySQL 8 localhost root user have all the privileges, but my server is in Google Cloud, so how can I grant all the privileges to the user I created?

When I run this query in the mysql-8 (I am using HeidiSQL to connect the DB and run query)

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user;
```

I got this output:

[image]

In this there are two root users:

1. For one host is localhost/127.0.0.1 (With all the privilege).
2. For other host is % (Not have any privilege).

I think I logged in as a user with `host-%` because my server is in `GCP`, that's why I cannot give any privilege to the user that I have created. So is there any way to give full permission to the

```
root@%
```

so that I can give full permission to the other users, Because I don't think there is any way to log in as a `root@localhost`

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are trying to create a super user, which is not something supported in cloud SQL, as you can see in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#:%7E:text=Cloud%20SQL%20does%20not%20support,use%20GRANT%20ALL%20ON%20%60%25%60):

> Cloud SQL does not support `SUPER` privileges, which means that `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` statements will not work. As an alternative, you can use `GRANT ALL ON` %`.*`.

This alternative mentioned could be enough to grant the permissions you expected.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL 8 on GCP SQL you **cannot** use:

```sql
GRANT ALL ON `%`.*
```

Users will only be granted access to the database with the name `%`.

This is because of the `partial_revokes` system flag. You can read the full details [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#partial-revokes).

The options available are:

1. Grant permissions to specific databases using the full database names

```sql
GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'testuser'@'%';
GRANT ALL ON db2.* TO 'testuser'@'%';
GRANT ALL ON db3.* TO 'testuser'@'%';
```

2. Use the grant and revoke command to grant user privileges on all database schemas while restricting access to a few database schemas.

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'testuser'@'%';
REVOKE SELECT ON test3_foobar.* FROM 'testuser'@'%';
```